# can a php getter function act on all members of the class?

Tags: php, class, getter

Suppose I have a class that includes several dates that are stored as DateTime variables

```
class gweek
{
public $today;    // when class is instatitated;
public $tomorrow; // day of week

function asSQLDate(){
    // want to use this with each datetime variable
}
}
```

What I'd like to do is be able to access each Datetime variable as SQL dates as in

```
$var->today->asSQLDate();
$var->tomorrow->asSQLDate();
```

But the only way I see to do this is to write a separate getter for each variable

```
function getTodayAsSQLDate(){
   return $this->Today->format ("Y-m-d");

function getTomorrowAsSQLDate(){
   return $this->Today->format ("Y-m-d");
```

It just seems that a getter function that can operate on several members of a class is preferable to a different getter function for each variable.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sidenote: https://itnext.io/php-7-4-setters-and-getters-have-died-2cefa996d26

Answer (score 1):

How would your getter function know which particular date you're interested in at any time? If you don't mind passing it a variable, it can work on both:

```
class gweek {
    function asSQLDate($which) {
        if ($which === "today") {
            // return $this->today formatted
        } else {
            // return $this->tomorrow formatted
        }
    }
}


$var->asSQLDate("today");
```

However, if `$today` and `$tomorrow` are instances of `DateTime`, they already have a `format()` method you can use:

```
$var->today->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

You could even extend `DateTime` to add a shorthand function for this and use that whenever you set the `$today` and `$tomorrow` variables:

```
class SqlDateTime extends DateTime
{
    function asSQLDate() {
        return $this->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
}

$var->today = new SqlDateTime("today");
$var->tomorrow = new SqlDateTime("tomorrow");

echo $var->today->asSQLDate();
// "2020-08-22 00:00:00"

echo $var->tomorrow->asSQLDate();
// "2020-08-23 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution but I  have created a class (dmdDate) that holds a DateTime variable and has a function asSQLDate.

In my main class, I then use that class like this

```
class gweek
{
public $today;
public $tomorrow; // day of week

public function __construct($time)
{
    $this->today = new dmdDate($time);

    $this->tomorrow = new dmdDate($this->today->date->modify("+1 day"));

}
```

} // end of class

and I can say

```
$time = new DateTimeImmutable();
$week = new gweek($time);

echo $week->today->asSQLDate(),br;
echo $week->tomorrow->asSQLDate ("Y-m-d");
```

So far this works as intended.  Stay tuned